# Python, Internal Server Error-File does not exist

Tags: python, .htaccess, internal-server-error

I am trying to run a simple Python Script on **Site5** Hosting Service. I uploaded the script in the cgi-bin folder. Once I try loading the script on the browser it throws an Internal Server Error. I checked the Error Log in Cpanel and it says that the "File does not exist". I tried to resolve the Issue by doing the following but unfortunately it still doesn't work-

1. Set File Permissions to 755
2. Tried testing by using hello.py and hello.cgi both throw the same error
3. Added this on the file hello.py #!/usr/bin/python
4. On the .htaccess file, added the line **Addhandler cgi-script .py .pl .cgi**
5. On the .htaccess file, under Directory Index added index.py and index.cgi

Here is my code-

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
print(“Hello World!”)
```

Kindly suggest on how this Issue can be resolved.

Comment: Does the error log say _which_ file doesn't exist?  Does `/usr/bin/python` exist?

Comment: @JohnGordon No it doesn't specify the file name. How do I check whether  /usr/bin/python exists or not?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Site5 so I can't give you specific instructions, but in general there are a few things you can try.  Does Site5 give you shell access?  If so, then just type `/usr/bin/python` at a command prompt and see what happens.  Does Site5 officially support python?  If so, they ought to have some documentation on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally resolved it. There was an Issue with my code. The parenthesis had to be removed. My final code was something like this

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n",
print "Hello world"
```

And it worked just as expected.

Comment: It's because the host is using a python versions 2.7, the parenthesis were introduced in python 3.0. For future reference.

Comment: @wind85 Thanks for letting me know. Would keep this in mind.